# Unpredictable soundcloud api tracklist

Tags: api, soundcloud

I need to get whole user's tracklist by SC api.
Before I use the next link format:

**[https://api.soundcloud.com/users/{user_id}/tracks/?page_size=200&linked_partitioning=1&client_id={app_id}](https://api.soundcloud.com/users/%7Buser_id%7D/tracks/?page_size=200&linked_partitioning=1&client_id=%7Bapp_id%7D)**

But it has stopped to work correct recently.
Changes:

- limit has been decreased by SC from 200 tracks to 50;
- returned tracks have become random (eg user has 300 tracks, but request above returns 54 tracks and link to the next page of tracks where fields **"offset=50&limit=50"** are appearing;
  when I change field **"page_size"** from 200 to 50, SC returns only 18 tracks).

Also I've tried to use fields **"offset"** and **"limit"** instead of "page_size" but it has worked incorrect, too.

How I can get whole user's tracklist?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the response and read `next_href` then change the url to the `next_href` value.
It's better to do this as a loop until there is no more `next_href`

Answer (score 0):

Some recent updates on pagination from the API can be found below. You need to rely on the cursor rather than offset

https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/pagination-updates-on-our-api